# Inconsistent output when reading binary file

Tags: c++, c++11, binaryfiles, readfile

Adapting some of the code I have seen in SO, I came out with the following solution:

```
fstream file("sample.bin", ios::binary | ios::in | ios::ate);

unsigned char charsRead[(int)file.tellg()];

file.read((char *) &charsRead, sizeof(char*));
for(int i=0; i<sizeof(charsRead); i++) 
    cout << (int) charsRead[i] << endl;
file.close();
```

It does compile, but every time is executed, it returns a different output. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Are you sure `sizeof(char*)` does what you think it does?

Comment: `unsigned char charsRead[(int)file.tellg()];` is a non standard VLA.  If you need to read into a `char` buffer consider a `std::vector<unsigned char>`.

Comment: Mmmm not really. But even when that number is a constant, it still returns different outputs when executing different times, so that does not explain the changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that the first 4 (or 8) bytes are ever equals and that the different output start from 5th or 9th byte.

As pointed by πάντα ῥεῖ, You read `sizeof(char*)` bytes (usually 4 or 8 bytes) and you print `sizeof(charsRead)` bytes.

If `sizeof(char*) < sizeof(charsRead)` (that is: if the dim of the file is bigger that 4 or 8), you write

- `sizeof(char*)` initialized chars
- `sizeof(charsRead) - sizeof(char*)` uninitialized chars (so, casual values).

Comment: I still do not understand something. Even if it is wrong, why is the output inconsistent given the same input file?

Comment: @AlvaroGomez - I've tryed to explain it in my answer; short answer: you're **not** reading the input file, you're printing random values

Answer (score 0):

I still do not understand the output, but I found a quite consistent solution for reading a binary file using a buffer.
http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/